# invalid email or password in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

It is very strange type error I have user and want to sign in through devise but I am facing strange error. I sign up successfully but when I try to login it through and error of invalid email or password here is may some code.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_filter :update_sanitized_params, if: :devise_controller?
    protected
    def update_sanitized_params

     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| u.permit(:email,   :password, :password_confirmation, :role)}
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password) }
   end   


 end
```

My form is

```
<h2>Sign in</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
  <% end -%>

   <div><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

and my devise.rb has following contents

```
 config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]
 config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]
 config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]
 config.reconfirmable = true
 config.password_length = 8..128
 config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
 config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

here is log

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in.user" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-11 10:52:50 +0500
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as 
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",    "authenticity_token"=>"SRARjzpSBMAck6qAOXHj4f4ycjYXX/1tYWoVrDhhylA=", "user"=>{"email"=>"asnad321@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'asnad321@gmail.com' ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 77ms
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's a bit hard to understand the issue. What is happening exactly?

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: simple I can not log in while my email and password are correct but i redirect to "/users/sign_in.user" and have contents "Invalid email or password."

Comment: What do your logs look like? I suspect that either your credentials are wrong, or devise just isn't properly installed/working.

Comment: Thanks guys for helping I have update my question with logs please check them out.

Comment: Just to be on safer side, did you check that the user you created is present in database? Fire up a query and check that a user with `email=asnad321@gmail.com` actually exists in the database or not.

Comment: My issue was solved when I restarted the server after running the migrations. For some reason, the server cached something and would not accept the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve the problem. The problem was with encrypt password there was a before save call back which encrypts the password but devise already have feature so password was encrypted twice. Thanks guys for help.